# Voting writes a debugging message to the javascript console

Tags: bug, status-completed, javascript

If you vote on any question or answer, the javascript console log spits out:

```
isElectionPrimary: false
```

This comes from `full.en.js` line 184:

```
console.log("isElectionPrimary: "+c);
```

Comment: Do you care? Do we care? How is this a bug?

Comment: Well it is strictly speaking true, it *isn't* an election primary. Or a bear

Comment: @RichardTingle http://giantgag.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/what-do-you-mean-im-not-a-bear-i-have-all-the-koalifications-funny-koala.jpg

Comment: Wow I'm watching my vote count go from -1 to 1 on this question over and over, I wish I had enough rep on meta to see the totals

Comment: @durron597 Its just someone having some fun, you currently have (+1|-0). You can tell this yourself because 1 upvote + 1 downvote gives a net +3 rep

Comment: Hah! Nice catch. I was able to reproduce this (I also may have toggled your vote count a little :P).

Comment: @bjb568 If every action you do on the site emitted a debugging message, would you still not care? I consider emitting a debugging message in production to be a bug.

Comment: @Stijn No, I wouldn't care. Why would I? I don't bother opening up the console, and if I did, I would be delighted to see some welcoming console.log()s.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This aberration has been terminated with extreme prejudice from the codebase.

With you in the next build (rev 2014.3.4.1421, meta rev 2014.3.4.2014).

Comment: ooh rev 2014. Win!